# performSegueWithIdentifier for didSelectRowAtIndexPath and IBAction

Tags: xcode, swift

The code would open the first ViewController and it works fine:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("openDates", sender: self.dates[indexPath.row])
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let tasksViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! TasksViewController
    tasksViewController.selectedList = sender as! Dates
}
```

This code opens the second ViewController but it doesn't work:

```
    @IBAction func ShowDetails(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("openDetails", sender: sender)
}
```

Error message:

> Could not cast value of type 'dante.DetailsViewController' (0x10b60b2e0) to 'dante.TasksViewController' (0x10b60adc0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling two separate segues and using the same code in `prepareForSegue` for both, which means you're trying to cast two separate view controllers to one view controller. Change your code to:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "openDates" {
        let tasksViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! TasksViewController
        tasksViewController.selectedList = sender as! Dates
    }
    else if segue.identifier == "openDetails" {
        let detailsViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailsViewController 
        // Do stuff
        // If you're not doing stuff, remove this else if block
        // The if statement will still catch and prepare the other segue
    }
}
```